# Import Varbinary(max) data using SQL Server/SSIS Data Import Wizard?

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, sql-server-2014, data-conversion

Is it even possible to import .csv flat file data into a SQL Server 2014 table using only the SSMS or SSIS Import/Export Wizards, if the table contains a varbinary(max) column?

I have searched hours and hours, and tried numerous configurations and different data types (e.g. DT_IMAGE) in both the SSMS and SSIS Import/Export Wizards to perform a simple, quick-n-dirty import of .csv file data into a four column table containing a varbinary(max) column in SQL Server.

I realize there are various other means to accomplish this by writing Trans SQL, using bulk-copy, adding column-import tasks, etc., but I find it hard to believe that I can't use the simple point-n-click configuration of the Import/Export Wizard, simply because the data happens to contain a varbinary(max) field, so I assume I must be doing something wrong.

Below are screen shots from the SSMS Import/Export Wizard...I get the same error in both SSMS and SSIS:

[image: SSMS Import/Export Wizard Columns]

[image: SSMS Import/Export Wizard Error Messages]

Comment: U have to provide a sample of the data.

Comment: Hadi, thanks for responding. While the rest of the fields are relatively small, the "Model" field has over 4K chars. What is the best way to provide the sample?

Comment: Store a sample to cloud and provide a link

Comment: Here you go: [Sample Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8zxmnpIfzMqVE41WTZIdllyb1E/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Anybody care to enlighten on the down vote(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use DT_TEXT An ANSI/MBCS character string with a maximum length of 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647) characters.
[Integration Service Data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types).
It Will be **varbinary(max)** in database.

[image]

I have used the sample data provide by you and imported it in the database.
[image]

Comment: I was prepared to respond that your answer didn't address my question because you stated: "It Will be **varchar(max)** in database" (Typo?), and my question was how to import the data into a table containing a varbinary(max) field. However, I decided to give it another shot, specifying DT_Text for the varbinary(max) field as you suggested, and changing the "Text Qualified" setting to True for all the input fields...All of which I would've sworn I had already tried. BUT, THIS time it worked! Strange, but in any case, Thank you very much! [Edit] Sorry not enough rep points for Upvote to display.